# Weeding out real agile from buzzword agile in an interview

Tags: agile, scrum

I've been interviewing for co-ops (paid internships) lately and a large number of the companies I've been interviewing with have been saying they use Scrum or some other agile methodology (scrum being the most popular).  I know that there are real agile shops and there are places which say they use an agile methodology but are really doing something else and using agile as a buzzword.

My question is, what are some questions I can ask in an interview which would separate these shops out?

EDIT: While I am looking for an internship, I feel that these questions are relevant for everyone.  The internship part is context.

Comment: Um, ask them if they are a pig or a chicken?

Comment: @Robert Lolwut?

Comment: @Matthew: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicken_and_the_Pig

Comment: @indyK1ng 1. Do you know any company that does real agile? 
2. Most of the time methodology should be adjusted to reality to vice versa. P.S. I agree regarding buzzword!

Comment: @Robert Ah, of course.  +1

Comment: @Amir That's the problem. I've only worked at two companies, one before they switched to buzzword agile and one where I was the only one working on the software project.  There are many companies, including big name ones which claim to be agile, but I haven't worked at them. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: @Robert They should answer: ["Blah blah Agile. Blah blah waterfall. Blah blah paradigm."](http://dilbert.com/2011-01-07/)

Answer (score 8):

I always begin by asking this question:

> **What's the duration of your iterations?**

Rate their answer:

1 week is awesome, 2 weeks is great, 3 is ok and 4 mediocre. Longer than that indicates they are struggling and more then 8 weeks is just weird. If the answer is *it depends*, you know they have no clue whatsoever.

Follow up with:

> **How often do you release?**

This is to verify the first question. The right answer is *daily* or *end of each sprint*. An agilist would know there should be no technical difference between an internal and external release.

Comment: The defacto standard is 2 - 4 weeks. 1 week sprints...? Hmm...I would be suspicious.

Comment: Once, 4 weeks was standard. Then 3, now it's 2. But I, and many with me, consider 1 week to be  better. Point is: shorter iterations => quicker releases, early feedback => more agile. Though, getting rid of iterations completely (Kanban) is probably where we are heading in the long run.

Comment: There is no "standard"; it varies between companies/teams/situations. I find the overhead of Scrum is, as a proportion of the sprint length, too wasteful for one-week sprints, therefore we use two.

Comment: @Christopher Good point. I think it's better to work to make the overhead shorter rather than making iterations longer.

Comment: I've tested many different duration and I like 1 for very small projects in small teams, but for large enterprise projects, 3 or 4 gave me better results.

Comment: For your definition of release, do you mean to testing or to the client.  If you say to client, that can only possibly work when you are on maintenance.  Even then, I still find it best to wait until a predefined set of changes are incorporated before the client gets it.

Comment: Iteration length: a project manager and a developer will have different definitions.  A project manager will see the week in development + the week in test as a 2 week iteration with 1 week overlap.  A developer will see it as just a 1 week iteration.  You can iterate too often.

Comment: @Berin The OP is asking about real (not watered down) agile software development. Your comments seems to question the validity of that development method and that is OK, but not what the question is about. For answers to your specific questions, look up "potentially shippable", "agile testing", "time boxed iteration" and "agile project manager".

Comment: I think its these terms of "real" vs. "watered down" agile that rile my feathers.  I've always applied the concepts and principles of the Agile Manifesto, but never used one of the branded versions of Agile.  Insisting on only one of the many agile methodologies violates the first tenet of the manifesto.  But I get what you are saying.

Comment: To me, "real" agile is agile that applies the manifesto and its 12 principles--regardless of what it's called.  There are a lot of buzzwords that add to the core meaning of agile and then claim you aren't agile if you don't do those.

Comment: @Berin I hear you and couldn't agree more: the manifesto is the foundation. No matter the method, I think that *awesome* agile is when you can release to users weekly/daily without needing a testing phase and everything works. That's is what I am aiming for.

Comment: @Martin, then, by your definition, a lot of projects on a lot of areas can never be "awesome" agile.

Comment: @Péter: If they release working software weekly or daily, then yes that is awesome. It's better than doing it every other week (which may still be good enough for the project). So on a broad scale I think this is a nice and simple way to compare agile projects.

Comment: @Martin, my point is that some types of projects / products just can't be realistically released to production daily or weekly. Or even if they technically could be, business doesn't allow it, and often for good reasons (try to upgrade the accounting software of a bank daily).

Comment: @Péter: I never said anything about release to production. In scrum, this is called "potentially releasable" and means it is complete, but not shipped yet. If the dev team produces software faster than the  business can digest, then the business is the constraint. There may be real valid impediments (legal, political, physical) which cannot be removed. So the business has to settle for "good enough", not awesome.

Comment: @Martin, OK then, to tell the truth it was unclear to me all the way what kind of release are you talking about. Thanks for clarifying :-)

Comment: This is an old answer, and things have changed a bit in my mind. Another acceptable answer to "How often do you release?" Is "Several times a week. Whenever it's ready to go." There are more and more folks aiming for flow based systems instead of iteration based ones.

Comment: "1 week is awesome": Huh? It depends on the problem. If you are fixing some small GUI bugs, you can release every day. If you are solving some complex problem then in one week you cannot even get started. And, no, you cannot break the problem into very small chunks because this "breaking the problem into small chunks" is part of "solving the problem" and sometimes it requires more than one week of work.

Answer (score 6):

Ask them to defend agile methodologies. And then ask them to refute it by outlining its weaknesses. Bonus points if they can navigate this course without littering it with meaningless buzzwords.

Comment: +1 It's always good to find ways to interview the company.

Comment: @Jeremy unfortunately they wouldn’t take it very well.  I wouldn't recommend it!

Comment: @Amir: Please explain! I have never left an interview without them asking if I have any questions. What's wrong with the job seeker wanting to know more about the company? If they don't take it well, then it's a sure sign I do not want to work for them!

Comment: I know some companies actually don't like it when their interviewee doesn't ask questions... to them it shows a lack of interest in the job.

Comment: @Jeremy I agree that you should fill free to any questions you want. But the really is different. In my experience all questions are not welcome.

Comment: @Amir: I apologize if I implied that you should ask any question you please. The wording of my comment was intentional. "It's always good to **find ways** ..." means ask your question intelligently.

Comment: @Jeremy No apologizes needed :)

Comment: I think asking them "to defend agile methodologies" is probably not the best method of asking ;)

Comment: @Matthrew: Yes. It would be better to ask them to define how *they* implement agile techniques.

Answer (score 6):

**Ask them why they use it**.

You will immediately know.

Comment: This can be answered pretty easily though with canned answers. "To reduce our time to market and remain competitive." It has to be a more back and forth approach. If the OP is familiar with Agile/Scrum and wants to be certain the business is as well; I would gather the OP should have a wealth of questions on the matter...specifically what bothered them at a previous place of employment and how might the new business address this.

Comment: The answer you mention could not be said by someone understanding agility. It's a pretty good indication they don't know why they should use scrum. Every company try to reduce time to market and remain competitive. If you answer me the question I would reply "it's the only methodology adapted to software development" or "it brings lot of visiblity on what we should improve".

Comment: @Pierre 303 Any reason to suggest why, from a business stance, that Agile adoption was a process which could increase our time to market and remain competitive with timely releases of our software is not valid and would define that individual as not knowing why the should use Scrum? You have to understand that the hiring managers are not always technically inclined but it doe snot mean the use of Scrum within the organizaiton is in vain.

Comment: I did't say it's not valid. I say it's not what someone that know agile very well will answer. Also I suppose he is interviewed by a developer since he is a developer. I never been interviewed by an hiring manager.

Comment: @Pierre 303 Can you elaborate your answer a bit? The reason for using any software development method is to "deliver value as efficient as possible to our customers" and that applies to agile as well as RUP and others.

Comment: @Martin to general to be honest. When you ask someone about something he will either say a general theorical description of the stuff. When he knows what he is talking about, he will usually use some specifics. In most case the specifics **he** was interested in. I gave my two specifics in my previous comment. It is explained by the way we think and answer questions. That's why asking **why** is so powerful in many situations. Check the body language too, it shows for 95% if the guy lie or is unconfortable with his answer. Check google for the word PNL.

Comment: @Pierre 303 Answering "deliver value efficient..." is a great and correct answer, but it doesn't tell *how* agile they are while doing it. And that, I think, is the problem with your answer. Oh, one should not have to read the comments to get the complete answer. So to be honest, I think you are making it a bit to easy for yourself here. But you have the best vote count, so more power to you :-)

Comment: @Martin: I don't think so. deliver value efficient.. is too "cliché". I talk to many people implementing Scrum (I'm still doing Agile Coaching and I did that for the past years), and that's how I determine the quality of implementation of a company I visit (sometimes for a very different matter). By asking **why**. I don't know the definition of making it easy for yourself, google didn't came up with a definition. Would you be so kind to teach me what it means ?

Comment: @Pierre 303: Yeah, cliché it may be. But still, it is why we are doing it and it's something many looses track of, especially developers. By "making it easy for yourself", I meant that you should elabore your question a bit more: "How will I immediately know?". As it stands now, I didn't learn much from your answer (but I'm sure I could sniff out fake-agilists quite easily anyway). So example of what a "correct" agile response would be for instance.

Comment: @Marting: I want to add that it's my technique to determine if the guy is lying or just bragging. Your technique may perfectly work too. I just upvoted you.

Comment: @Marting: fair enough. I try again. When you are asked why, and depending on how you are conditioned (usually when you are asked why, it means you have to justify yourself, which is stupid, but it's how it is now...) you immediately trigger specific parts of the brain. When you are good with something, you will never tell cliché sentence like the one you suggest. Never. Try with your wife or kids today. However, when you are unsure or don't want to look stupid, you use cliché sentences you heard in a meeting or something. That combined with the body language helps you determine if it's true.

Comment: @Martin: And you don't have to read books on PNL. Human being is instinctive enough to make the difference between an obvious lie and the truth. Asking **why** is just the trigger.

Comment: @Pierre 303: It is true that saying something you don't believe in  will sound hollow. I'd never quote unless I could back it up personally. In this case: talking about "customer value" (user stories for instance) is a **great** way change focus from technical tasks and the only way to prioritize. And "efficient" here means to release early so we get feedback asap.

Comment: Totally agree. Ask them why they even chose Agile. Solid. +1

Answer (score 5):

I would ask them to describe the software development life cycle when using the Agile methodology. If they're familiar with it they should be able to describe each phase in the SDLC accurately.

**EDIT**: I just realized that you were asking from the point of view of the interviewee, not the interviewer. In that case I would probably ask them about their SDLC and see if the steps they say they take matches up to what Agile really is.

Comment: Good point regarding asking about SDLC. However I have been in organization where they followed all step in SDLC but the **team** applied the methodology badly.

Comment: @Amir: If that were the case I would assume they were at least trying to follow the agile methodology. Chances are they either have a good reason for deviating away from it, or they don't know what they're doing and would be willing to learn if you took the time to teach them.

Comment: They do have good reason. They adapt the methodology to their reality.

Answer (score 3):

The approach I take really has little to do with the agile buzzwords, but it does have to do with agile practices.  One of the commonalities in all agile teams is the short iteration, most people get that part (it's one of the [12 principles](http://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html) behind agile on the http://agilemanifesto.org site).  The purpose of the short iteration is to get feedback early on the quality of the software developed.  This is where I start.

1. Ask about unit testing.  Overwhelmingly the answer I get here has been "uh, we cut that out because we didn't have enough time"  (note: first 2 warning flags--no time and no unit testing)
2. Ask about when the software was tested, and how often.  Answers can get creative here.  Particularly if the team uses "Agile" as an excuse to throw all process aside.  If the answer is toward the end of the project, or anything other than with each iteration, they don't know what agile is.

So far, I haven't had to go any further than this to know that the person doesn't know what agile is.  I've also only been in one interview with a company that already had well established agile processes in place.

There's more than one way to do agile, and I care more about the principles of agile than any particular brand or buzzword.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that separate those who are "doing" agile from those who are agile:

- Ask about continuous integration if they're not using CI deduct a point. Add a point if they are. Extra points:

  1. Add 1 if they use two phase commits (code must successfully build before the developer can check in).
  2. Add 1 if the build script includes running a test suite
  3. Add 1 if the build fails if code coverage falls beneath a certain threshold
  4. Add 2 if it is possible to deploy the application so that is ready to run in one click
- Ask about TDD (test-driven development) subtract 2 points if they don't use TDD add 1 if they do.
- Ask about iterations, how long are they (subtract 2 points if they don't do iterative development, subtract 1 if the iteration is longer than a month or less than two weeks, add 1 if its 2 weeks)
- Ask how estimation is done add 1 if they use story points, add 2 if they do planning poker or something similar, subtract one if they use absolute time estimates, subtract 2 if developers aren't involved in the estimation process.
- Ask how features are built add 1 if a developer is responsible for the feature from top to bottom (vertical slice) subtract 1 if developers are responsible for a specific layer (horizontal slice)

There are a number of other indicators, but those alone should give you a good picture if the team actually IS agile. A team with 5 points or more qualifies. Anything else means they're "doing" agile. Agile is not just about iterations, it's about enabling the team to adapt to change easily. If you're iteratively writing untested, muddled code, written under external pressures, well you're just writing crap code in iterations. Notice that you can get a lot of points just from the continuous integration bullet. But that alone isn't enough to bring you over 5 if you're not following the other practices.

Comment: "Ask about TDD (test-driven development) subtract 2 points if they don't use TDD add 1 if they do" makes no sense. Just add 3 if they do.

Comment: I see what you're saying...I didn't simplify my formula...but I think my point is clear.

Comment: WTF has CI and TDD to do with Agile? Sure, makes releasing easier but you really don't *need* it to work in an agile way. And believe me, I know companies with TDD and CI that are NOT agile whatsoever.

Comment: TDD and CI alone does not make an environment agile. However, missing those elements is a warning sign that there isn't a true commitment to being agile.

Answer (score 2):

As with all of these things you **ask for real world examples from projects they've worked on**, not theory.  Accepting theoretical answers is the easiest way to be duped by someone who hasn't actually been there.

So you **ask to speak to actual developers** and ask things like:

- So talk me through your current project.  What was the initial end goal?  What did the first sprint contain and what could the software do at the end of it?
- Can you give me examples of functionality or design on your last project you believe worked out differently than had you done it as a waterfall project?
- Give me an example of how a large piece of functionality was broken down over multiple sprints?  What inefficiencies / rework did this lead to?  And what improvements or changes from what was initially envisioned.
- When you started working with agile, what things that you were doing during the early sprints did you change during later sprints (or projects) as you got to grips with the methodology?

**Keep bringing them back to the actual projects** - what were they trying to achieve, examples of what was in each sprint, examples of the sorts of things that came up in meetings, examples of interactions with the users.

**Do not accept theory, do not accept other people's projects, only things they themselves have worked on and can talk about from first hand experience.**

They would have to be a stunningly good liar to be able to make up 10 - 15 minutes worth of stuff that would get past you if you know your stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to make them defensive, I've found the following question will initiate a conversation that will tell you everything you need to know about whether they are actually using an Agile approach or just paying it lip service:

> Who is responsible for writing requirements/specifications for your software projects?

I have seen numerous companies who claimed to be agile and even wanted a Scrum Master certification describe a classic big up-front design process when you ask about their requirements gathering process.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that stands out to me is that you're looking for an internship, which leads me to wonder what your purpose is in asking these questions. Are you trying to ask a question about agile to make the interview go well, or would you actually refuse an offer from a company using buzzword agile? If you're really looking for an agile environment, pick a question (why do you use agile, what time are your standups, how long are iterations, whatever), and ask it over the phone or in an email without wasting time on an interview. If you're looking for income, wait for the interview, and ask questions that show your knowledge/excitement about agile methodologies (Tell me about your software development lifecycle) without embarrassing the interviewer if they're using some semi-agile abomination.

Comment: This is a question I would ask during the "Do you have any questions for me" portion of the interview. I'm asking a question to determine if they're telling the truth when they're saying they are agile.  I've already been in a cowboy environment and would like to prevent that from happening. I know that there are organizations that use agile as a buzzword, so I'm trying to filter those out. Also, interviews go both ways, I'm interviewing the company while they're interviewing me.

Answer (score 1):

I ask them to describe a typical request, from inception to finaly delivery to client.

I also ask whether they typically handle long-term support for the product they provide the client (because teams that do will generally build a better product, knowing they're gonna be the one fixing it at 1AM on Sunday during Labor Day weekend).

I also ask how management sees its role during the process. It's pretty easy to see if they have the fire-and-forget attitude (we launch, you fly, we ask if you hit the target) or the "we help you row the boat up the river" attitude.

These will generally show you how they really do things, not how they're Supposed to do them, or how they Claim to do them.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to see if someone knows what they are doing from an SDLC perspective is to ask them where they have screwed up in the past, and how they would do it differently.  People who've been through the process a few times and will fully admit where they screwed up, and the are generally pretty detailed about.  They openness to discuss it shows a level of confidence, because they admit they aren't perfect.  Avoiding the question by saying "They pretty much do it OK all the time," is a real warning sign.

Answer (score 1):

How often they release to production. The longer the time the less Agile they are.
How often they have reflection workshops. If they know what you are talking about then good.
How often do they have team 'catchup' meetings. Daily is great, monthly is bad.
Do they have a continuous integration server. This isn't a must have but will give you an idea about their use of tools.
How often do the end users sit with the developers. Never means they aren't Agile.

Comment: +1 IMO, the first thing that dies in an agile-wannabe organization is the retrospective. That's really more a Scrum concept, but successful agile comes with understanding how well your process is enabling instead of disabling your organization. Without some introspection mechanism I don't see how that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

- Give them a situation and ask them to solve it in agile way;
- Ask them about their favorite agile practices (planning poker, pair programming, bdd/tdd, kanban);
- Ask them why they did not choose or moved from *other* methodologies (waterfall, rup, etc.)
- What are most known people in agile methodology world, who coined the term and what most popular books are written about it.

Comment: Honestly, I would fail the fourth point.  I know what agile is, and I've read a number of online resources about how different people walked stuff out.  However, my path to agile has always been custom to the team/environment I work on.

Answer (score 0):

If they are using Scrum, you could ask if you could watch the next stand-up.  If they don't have them, then ask why not as that would usually be part of the methodology.

There are some aspects to Agile that could also be worth mentioning.  Ask to see the story board, how big is the back log, or what were some of the highlights in the last retrospective, for a few other ideas.  The key here being to get to something tangible that shows what is happening compared to just fluffy words that don't really mean much.

Answer (score 0):

Ask them how they handle design. If they tell you there's no design in agile, they aren't getting it.

Ask them how they manage changing requirements. If it sounds like changing requirements has its own process, they probably aren't getting it.

If they're claiming to use Scrum, look to see how they write it. Shops that do Scrum well tend to know well enough how to write it. Hint: it's not SCRUM.

That may seem like pedantry, but I'm firmly of the belief that in order to successfully apply a process template like Scrum, RUP, XP, or whatever, you need to understand the philosophy and the "why" so you know how to adapt the "what" to your organization. In Scrum, most folks who are doing their homework will come across that little bit of info. Folks who are looking for cookbook recipes for project management will usually miss that detail.

Answer (score 0):

What makes sense to me is to ask them to describe how they handle part of the Agile process. Right now my favorite is the beginning of an iteration, but you might develop your own favorite.

Ask: "given a pile of tickets at the beginning of the sprint, describe your workflow from here"

Key points to listen for here:

- Do the devs estimate the tickets?
- Do you keep track of velocity?
- What happens when your estimates come to more than your velocity?
- What happens when your estimates come to more than your velocity when you have a deadline? *(Watch for spin here: do they reduce complexity, or reprioritize, or just deathmarch the development team?)*

None of these are deal breakers by themselves, but if their answers to enough of these questions make you wonder, then maybe they're interested in agile *rituals*, not actual agile *development*.